# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{9+10x^2+x^4}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{9+10x^2+x^4}dx$$

The idea is to use contour integration. So I know I can factor the denominator to $(x^2+1)(x^2+9)$ but don't know where to go from here. any hints would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: @Mikasa geer kardam, nemidoonam bayad che kar konam

Comment: I think the below step-wise answer illustrates what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{9+10x^2+x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathfrak{Re}\left(e^{ix}\right)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\mathfrak{Re}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)(x-i)(x+3i)(x-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}x\right).$$ To evaluate this, you should use a contour with two parts: $\gamma_R=\gamma_{R_0}\cup\gamma_{R_1},$ where $\gamma_{R_0}:[-R,R]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\,\gamma_{R_0}(t)=t,$ and $\gamma_{R_1}:[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\,\gamma_{R_1}(t)=Re^{it},$ so that $\gamma_{R_0}$ is the diameter of a circle, and $\gamma_{R_1}$ is the upper semicircle. As such, the contour $\gamma_R$ encloses the singularities $i$ and $3i.$ Therefore, what you have is that $$\oint_{\gamma_R}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)(x-i)(x+3i)(x-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}x=2\pi{i}\left[\lim_{x\to{i}}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)(x+3i)(x-3i)}+\lim_{x\to3i}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)(x-i)(x+3i)}\right]=2\pi\left(\frac1{16e}-\frac1{48e^3}\right)=\frac{\pi}8\left(\frac1{e}-\frac1{3e^3}\right)$$ and $$\oint_{\gamma_R}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)(x-i)(x+3i)(x-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\gamma_{R_0}}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)(x-i)(x+3i)(x-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)(x-i)(x+3i)(x-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Therefore, $$\int_{\gamma_{R_0}}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)(x-i)(x+3i)(x-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)(x-i)(x+3i)(x-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}8\left(\frac1{e}-\frac1{3e^3}\right).$$ This is equivalent to $$\mathfrak{Re}\left[\int_{\gamma_{R_0}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]=\mathfrak{Re}\left[\int_{\gamma_{R_0}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]+\mathfrak{Re}\left[\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]=\int_{\gamma_{R_0}}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x+\mathfrak{Re}\left[\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]=\frac{\pi}8\left(\frac1{e}-\frac1{3e^3}\right),$$ which is equivalent to $$\int_{\gamma_{R_0}}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}8\left(\frac1{e}-\frac1{3e^3}\right)-\mathfrak{Re}\left[\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x\right].$$ Notice that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_{R_0}}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ so $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}8\left(\frac1{e}-\frac1{3e^3}\right)-\lim_{R\to\infty}\mathfrak{Re}\left[\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x\right].$$ Since $\mathbb{C}$ forms a Banach space over $\mathbb{R},$ $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\mathfrak{Re}\left[\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]=\mathfrak{Re}\left[\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x\right],$$ hence $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}8\left(\frac1{e}-\frac1{3e^3}\right)-\mathfrak{Re}\left[\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x\right].$$ All that remains is to prove that $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_{R_1}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,\mathrm{d}x=0.$$ However, I will leave that to you as an exercise.

Comment: what do you mean by $\mathfrak{Re}$? Real part?

Comment: and are those just a bunch of different ways of doing it ?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Yes, $\mathfrak{Re}$ refers to the real part. They are all just one method. I essentially walked you through all the steps, with the hope that none of the steps are confusing. Hopefully, now, if you were to try a similar problem, you would be able to understand how to do it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

**STEPS:**

- $\cos x=\Re(e^{ix})$
- continue the contour on the upper side. Why? $$z=x+iy\\e^{iz}=e^{ix}e^{-y}$$So for $y>0$ the limit at infinity goes to zero.
- factor further the denominator into $(x-i)(x+i)(x-3i)(x+3i)$
- See which piles are in the upper half
- ...

If you have issue with the first step, split the integral into an integral of $e^{iz}$ and an integral of $e^{-iz}$. But for one you need to integrate the upper half plane, for the other one you integrate the lower half plane (see the reason in the second step).